# python - Is it possible concatenate a string in equation?

Tags: python, string, equation

I have variables of all the months and is better to change a month one time at the start than all the script. Not focus on the counts, only in understanding of python.

Is it possible?
My variable is *uqFEB* (and I have *uqJAN, uqMAR*...).

```
uqFEB = xarray.DataArray: lat: 721, lon: 1440

month = 'FEB'
```

The expectative is to write somenthing like this:

```
x = uq+{'month'}+*2
```

or

```
 x = uq'month'*2
```

And python substitute and understand:

```
x= uqFEB*2
```

How can I write this syntax? It's possible?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you need. Regardless, `x = uq+{'month'}+*2` is not valid syntax. `{}` declares a dictionary but needs a key and value.

Comment: You could instead use a dictionary to keep track of the values you need to, for instance:
`months = {"JAN": some_value_jan, "FEB": some_value_feb ...}` and when needed you could just call: `x = months["FEB"] * 2`

Comment: Can you show examples of what you're trying to achieve? Like what do you expect `uq + {'month'}+*2` to do?

Comment: Anytime you are thinking "Variable variable" or "Dynamically referencing a variable" think instead "Dictionary". In every language this is true.

Comment: I have, for example, uqFEB = xarray.DataArray: lat: 721, lon: 1440. And the others months the same. My problem is, I want put all theses uqFEB (variable) in equation automatically, not typing, somenthing like "uq+{'month'}+*2"

Comment: My problem is the name recognition of variable (uqFEB), not the values. I need a manner to write 'month = FEB' and in equation for example, write x = uq((month))*2 and the python understand x = uqFEB*2.

Comment: Assignment, not equation.

Comment: Maybe, but after I need to use 'uqFEB' in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment (and others) you want a dictionary. Any time you are thinking of dynamically referencing a variable in your code, think "Dictionary" instead:

```
month_dict={"Jan":1, "Feb":2, "Mar":3, "Apr":4, "May":5, "Jun":6, "Jul":7, "Aug":8, "Sept":9, "Oct":10, "Nov":11, "Dec":12}
x=month_dict["Feb"]**2
print(x)
```

```
4
```